# ServiceMix 7.x : feature installs/starts but bundle dependency never starts

Tags: classloader, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

ServiceMix 7.0.1
Windows 7; Java 1.8.x
commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar (note: the jar is a bundle; does not need to be wrapped)

```
<features name="smx7-test" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0">
<feature name="smx7-test" version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT">
    <bundle dependency="true" start="true">mvn:commons-io/commons-io/2.4</bundle>
</feature>
```

Something different in ServiceMix 7.x (7.0.1) that I am missing or I need to configure a standard feature or other?

The commons-io jar/bundle dependency in the features.xml (above) never starts after the feature is installed/started. This is not isolated to just the commons-io jar/bundle. I have the same issue with the antlr-runtime-4.7.jar and commons-beanutils.jar among others. I have just setup a small sample test-case to quickly deploy and test using commons-io.

- I start with a pristine servicemix 7.0.1 install.
- I place the features.xml file (above) in the system repo: system/smx7/smx7-test/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/smx7-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-features.xml
- I place the commons-io-2.4 jar in the system repo: system/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
- Start servicemix 7.0.1 (servicemix.bat). All good so-far.
- The feature installs fine with the following commands:

  feature:repo-add mvn:smx7/smx7-test/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
  feature:install smx7-test
- I can do a feature:list | grep smx7-test and the feature shows as installed and started.

  karaf@root>feature:list | grep smx7-test
  smx7-test  | 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT   | x        | Started     | smx7-test

BUT a bundle:list in the karaf console indicates the common-io bundle is not in the listing. If i duplicate all above in servicemix 6.x all works as expected. That is the commons-io bundle is listed and started.

If i try to deploy a business layer bundle in the 7.0.1 instance above, that wants to import a commons-io package/class the business layer bundle will never start (shows only as installed). The error in the servicemix.log is as expected since the commons-io bundle never started : 
**missing requirement** [test [222](R 222.2)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

Note: the commons-io-2.4 jar/bundle MANIFEST.MF Export-Package contents is/are backwards compatible hence the version parameters in the error above. I tried modifying my business layer bundle MANIFEST.MF to allow for the range indicated above and it had no impact.

Any ServiceMix 7 suggestions welcome!!

Comment: Just because you put a JAR in the systems/repo folder does not mean its automatic installed.

Comment: Thank you Claus. I understand that I cannot just drop a JAR/Bundle into systems/repo. I tried to explain in the description that I add the JAR to the system folder as well as a features.xml that lists the JAR as a dependency. I then issue the following commands in the Karaf console to add the feature to the repo and then install it. 
  feature:repo-add mvn:smx7/smx7-test/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features 
  feature:install smx7-test